# Não sei da viabilidade de fazer em lambda ou linq a minha expressão

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Tenho essas duas listas:

```
List<string> dirZipDireto = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Dir_Zip_Direto"].Split(';').ToList();
List<string> arquivos = Directory.GetFiles(caminhoCommiter, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

Para minimizar linhas de código e dar mais beleza e consistência ao código, creio que eu posso melhorar isso e evitar alguns foreach. O que eu quero:

Gostaria de carregar a lista `arquivos` com arquivos, exceto os que existem na lista de diretórios `dirZipDireto`. Logo o código referente  a `arquivos` pode ser minimizado e em uma única expressão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que tal?

```
var arquivosFiltrados = (from arquivo in arquivos
                         where !(from dirEvitar in dirZipDireto
                                 where arquivo.Contains(dirEvitar)
                                 select dirEvitar).Any()
                         select arquivo).ToList();
```

Comment: Jônatas, so uma pergunta. Se eu quiser acrescentar mais uma lista de arquivos à var arquivosFiltrados, nessa mesma linq, como eu faço? Tentei algumas formas aqui e não consegui adicionar.

Comment: Resolvi com um Union o comentário acima.